# Polymorphic relation in laravel for following a user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I've a `User` model and a `likes` table. I applied polymorphic relation to it.

`likes` table has the following structure:

```
user_id --- likeable_id ---- likeable_type
eg: 1 ---- 5 ---- App\User  //This indicates user 1 follows 5
eg: 3 ---- 1 ---- App\User  //This indicates user 3 follows 1
```

Now I'm trying to get the followers and following list.

In the `User` model I added

```
 public function likes()
  {
        return $this->morphMany(Like::class, 'likeable');
  }

    public function followers()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Like', 'likeable_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

and from the controller, I've tried to do this:

```
$user1 = User::with('followers')->where('username', $username)->first();
```

But it's returning `null` for the `followers` relation. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer by myself: In `User` model -

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Like', 'likeable')->with('user');
}

public function following()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Like', 'user', 'likeable_type')->with('user');
}
```